# Add class to another element of shared class on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two containers, one is a grid of boxes with text inside of each box, and the other is a list of links.

In each container, a box and an item will be sharing a class.

I want to hover over one of the links and add classes to children of the box that shares the same class as the link.

I can do this by using

```js
$(function(){
$(".item-list").children(".class-one").mouseover(function() {
  $("#grid").children(".class-one").children("h1").addClass("red").siblings("p").addClass("purple");
    });
    $(".item-list").children(".class-one").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#grid").children(".class-one").children("h1").removeClass("red").siblings("p").removeClass("purple");
    });
    $(".item-list").children(".class-two").mouseover(function() {
    $("#grid").children(".class-two").children("h1").addClass("red").siblings("p").addClass("purple");
    });
    $(".item-list").children(".class-two").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#grid").children(".class-two").children("h1").removeClass("red").siblings("p").removeClass("purple");
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

#grid .box {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#grid .box h1, p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: blue;
}

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item-list a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: goldenrod;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


.item-list a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.red {
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.purple {
  color: purple !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="box class-one">
      <h1>Box One</h1>
      <p>box one right here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box class-two">
      <h1>Box Two</h1>
      <p>box two right here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-list">
    <a class="class-one">Item One</a>
    <a class="class-two">Item Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this seems like it would get out of hand very quickly, since I plan to have a lot of the same classes and I don't want to repeat the same code over and over again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would urge you to read up on [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) – you should never need to use `!important` in your own CSS especially in a section so small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event delegation` with JQuery's `.on` for this:

```js
 $(function(){
        //This fires the event whenever an anchor element of element with 
        //className item-list has mouseover
        $(".item-list").on('mouseover', 'a', function(){
            //Get the class of the anchor which corresponds to the box
            const anchorClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/); //Get the classes of the anchor
            const anchorClassIWant = anchorClasses.filter(function(c) { return c.indexOf("class-") > -1 ;});
            //use the class of the anchor in our selector to get the proper grid elements
            $("#grid").children("." + anchorClassIWant).children("h1").addClass("red").siblings("p").addClass("purple");
        });
        
         //This fires the event whenever an anchor element of element with 
        //className item-list has mouseleave
        $(".item-list").on('mouseleave', 'a', function(){
             //Get the class of the anchor which corresponds to the box
            const anchorClasses = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/); //Get the classes of the anchor
            const anchorClassIWant = anchorClasses.filter(function(c) { return c.indexOf("class-") > -1 ;});
            //use the class of the anchor in our selector to get the proper grid elements
            $("#grid").children("." + anchorClassIWant ).children("h1").removeClass("red").siblings("p").removeClass("purple");
        });

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

#grid .box {
  padding: 2rem;
}

#grid .box h1, p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: blue;
}

.item-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item-list a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  color: goldenrod;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


.item-list a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.red {
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.purple {
  color: purple !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="box class-one">
      <h1>Box One</h1>
      <p>box one right here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box class-two">
      <h1>Box Two</h1>
      <p>box two right here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-list">
    <a class="class-one">Item One</a>
    <a class="class-two">Item Two</a>
  </div>
</div>
```